# Derivative w.r.t $x$ of $f(x) = \int_1^x( t^3+t) \,dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Derivative w.r.t $x$ of $f(x) = \int_1^x (t^3+t)\, dt$

Is it true that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^x(t^3+t)\,dt = x^3+x$$

If not, how does one evaluate this derivative? Also, I would like to see both the technical proof of why this is true as well as an intuitive explanation. Thank you!

Comment: This is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: This is called [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is the Leibniz integral rule and it can proved by the Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Indeed, let $u(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt$ and assuming the the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ can be commuted with the integral, we consider the antiderivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,t)=f(x,t)$.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC), we have $$u(x)=F(x,b)-F(x,a),$$

and differentiating gives

\begin{align}
u'(x)&=F_{x}(x,b)+F_{b}(x,b)b'(x)-F_{x}(x,a)-F_{a}(x,a)a'(x) \\
&=F_{b}(x,b)b'(x)-F_{a}(x,a)a'(x)+[F_{x}(x,b)-F_{x}(x,a)] \\
&=b'(x)f(x,b)-a'(x)f(x,a)+[F_{x}(x,b)-F_{x}(x,a)]
\end{align}

And applying the FTC again, we obtain $$u'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\!\!\!f(x,t)\,dt=b'(x)f(x,b)-a'(x)f(x,a)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\!\!\!f_{x}(x,t)\,dt.$$

---

So in your example we have $a(x)=1$, $b(x)=x$ and $f(x,t)=t^{3}+t$ (comparing with above) so we have $$u'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{x}\!(t^3+t)\,dt=\frac{d}{dx}(x)f(x,x)-\frac{d}{dx}(1)f(x,1)+\int_{1}^{x}\!\!\!f_{x}(x,t)\,dt$$
$$=x^{3}+x-0+0=x^{3}+x$$

Note $f_{x}$ means the partial derivative of $f$ wrt to $x$ and since $f$ does not depend on $x$, so it is $0$.