# Solution of initial value problem $u(t)=\frac{1}{v} \int_0^t \sin(v(t-s))f(s)ds$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm fairly new to the concept of differential equations so maybe you can give me some hints to how to solve this initial value problem.

Solution:

$$u(t)=\frac{1}{v} \int_0^t \sin(v(t-s))f(s)~ds.$$

Initial value problem:

$$u''(t) +v^2u(t)=f(t)\text{ and }u(0)=u'(0)=0.$$

Well I suppose I have to look if the solution satisfies both formulas.

I tried this by using partial integration and expressing $u(t)$ as $f(t)$ since i have trouble integrating that part.

I found that

$$f(x)=v^2(u(t)+\frac{1}{v^2}\cos(vt)f(0)+\int_0^t \frac{1}{v} cos(vt-vs)f'(s)~ds.$$

When I plugged that in $u''(t) +v^2u(t)=f(t),$ I got:

$$u''=cos(vt)f(0)+v^2\int_0^t \frac{1}{v} cos(vt-vs)f'(s)~ds.$$

My question is how I can move on from there and if I'm doing it right. If not: Please give me hints & tips how to solve such problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to check it satisfies the initial conditions $u(0)=u'(0)=0$.

By the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we have $$u'(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\cos(v(t-s))f(s)ds$$

and  $$u''(t)=f(t)-v\int_{0}^{t}\sin(v(t-s))f(s)ds.$$

Thus $$u''(t) +v^2u(t)=f(t)$$ as required. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832347/derivative-w-r-t-x-of-fx-int-1x-t3t-dt/3832362#3832362).

Comment: Okay, so I made a mistake since my $u''$ is different from your $u''$. Or do i have to revert the partial integration? And you're right, i still have to check if u(0) = u'(0) = 0. But isn't that trivial since $\int_y^y f(x)dx$ is always equal to 0 if the function is differentiable?

Comment: Yes $u(0)=0$ is trivial to check, but to check $u'(0)=0$ you have to compute $u'(t)$ and then it becomes trivial. You have to compute the derivatives $u'(t)$ and $u''(t)$ and then substitute into $u''(t) +v^2u(t)=f(t)$ to show that it is satisfied. The derivatives are computed using the Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: Thus we've shown that $u(t)$ satisfies both the initial conditions and the differential equation, hence it is the correct solution.